# GNU i386-Assembler: arch/i386/boot.S: Error: junk `GDT39' after expression

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, nasm, gnu-assembler

I try to follow the tutorial from wiki.osdev.org about the setup of a GDT. I tried to convert the example code from NASM to GAS Syntax but the tool intel2gas couldn't convert some lines which I then tried by myself.
I have to say that I know not very much about assembler.
This is my code from boot.S and I am using the GNU-i386-Cross-Compiler:

```
    # Declare constants for the multiboot header.
.set ALIGN,    1<<0             # align loaded modules on page boundaries
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1             # provide memory map
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO  # this is the Multiboot 'flag' field
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002       # 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS) # checksum of above, to prove we are multiboot

.section .rodata


# Declare a header as in the Multiboot Standard.
.section .multiboot
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM

# Reserve a stack for the initial thread.
.section .bss
.align 16
stack_bottom:
.skip 16384 # 16 KiB
stack_top:

# The kernel entry point.
.section .text
.global _start
.type _start, @function
_start:
    movl $stack_top, %esp

    # Call the global constructors.
    call _init

    # Transfer control to the main kernel.
    call kernel_main

    # Hang if kernel_main unexpectedly returns.
    cli
1:  hlt
    jmp 1b
.size _start, . - _start

gdtr:   .word 0
    .long 0

setGdt:
    xorl %eax,%eax
    movw %ds,%ax
    shll $4,%eax
    addl $''GDT'', %eax
    movl [gdtr + 2], %eax
    movl $''GDT_end'', %eax
    subl $''GDT'', %eax
    movw %ax, gdtr
    lgdt [gdtr]
    ret
```

That is also the almost the same file as described at OSDev.org in the Meaty Skeleton article.

My Errors are:

```
arch/i386/boot.S: Assembler messages:
arch/i386/boot.S:51: Error: junk `GDT39' after expression
arch/i386/boot.S:53: Error: junk `GDT_end39' after expression
arch/i386/boot.S:54: Error: junk `GDT39' after expression
```

I cant really explain what these mean.
If you need any further information just ask.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes in `$''GDT''` and similar expressions are not valid GAS syntax.  Don't do that, just use `mov $GDT_end, %eax` / `sub $GDT, %eax`.

Or better, compute this constant at assemble time with `mov $GDT_end - GDT, %eax`

---

GAS is probably choking on those, or treating the whole thing as a character literal since it starts with `'`.  But GAS makes a total mess of parsing character literals with more than one character after the `'`.

I assume its parsing code is pretty simplistic and hacky,
since `mov $'a, %eax` (no close quote) assembles the same as `mov $'a', %eax`

And `mov $'abcd', %eax` produces the errors:

```
foo.s:1: Error: backward ref to unknown label "97:"
foo.s:1: Error: junk `cd44%eax' after expression
foo.s:1: Error: number of operands mismatch for `mov'
```

`1b` would be a backward reference to the label `1:` (the most recent instance on a previous line).  The ASCII code for `'a'` is `97`, so somehow the `ab` part of it convinced GAS to treat it as `$97b`, forgetting about the single quotes.  And `44` is the ASCII code for `','`.

**Your errors are just the kind of nonsense GAS produces when you have more than one non-`'` character following as single-quote** in a context where it wants an integer constant expression (like after a `$` as an immediate).

**`39` (decimal) is the ASCII code for `'` single-quote.**

Better assemblers like NASM let you do `mov eax, 'abcd'` to get EAX = 0x64636261, ready to store into memory to get those ASCII bytes in source order.  But GAS very much doesn't, and its parser didn't consider the possibility anyone would even try.

Comment: Thank you, that was a really big help for me as an assembly-noob.